# Update file descriptor pointing to /proc/self after fork() from python multiprocess.Process

Tags: subprocess, fork, file-descriptor

I'm working on a C++ program that uses boost::python to provide a python wrapper/API for the user. The program tracks and limits its own memory usage by opening /proc/self/statm using a file descriptor. Every timestep it seeks to the beginning of that file and reads the vmsize from it.

`proc_self_statm_fd = open( "/proc/self/statm", O_RDONLY );`

However, this causes a problem when calling fork(). In particular, when a user writes a python script that does something like this:

`proc = multiprocessing.Process(name="bkg_process",target=bkg_process,daemon=True)`

The problem is that the forked process gets the file descriptor pointing to /proc/self/statm from the parent process, not its own, and this reports the wrong memory usage. Even worse, if the parent process exits, the child process will fail when trying to read from the file descriptor.

What's the correct solution for this? It needs to be handled at the C++ level because we don't have control over the user's python scripts. Is there a way to have the class auto detect that a fork has happened and grab a new file descriptor? In the worst case I can have it re-open the file for every update. I'm worried that would add runtime overhead though.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the PID in the class, and check it against the value of `getpid()` on each call, and then reopen the file if the PID has changed.  `getpid()` is typically much cheaper than `open` - on some systems it doesn't even need a context switch (it just fetches the PID from a magic location in the process's own memory).

That said, you may also want to actually measure the cost of reopening the file each time - it may not actually be significant.